# SWIFT model for parsing JSON

Tags: json, swift, codable

I need to parse the data of JSON. For this I will use the protocol **Codable**.
The json received looks like this (this is the part that interests me):

```
(
    {
        description = mySecondGist;
        files =         {
            "gistfile1.txt" =             {
                filename = "gistfile1.txt";
                language = Text;
                "raw_url" = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/VladimirKhuraskin/9ca2362c09cebcc16bd74f51f267231a/raw/74caacd3ad3eedb369a07b926327d2ef37e3eefc/gistfile1.txt";
                size = 17;
                type = "text/plain";
            };
        };
    }
)
```

I made this model:

```
struct Gists: Codable {
    var description: String?
    var files: DetailGist?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case description
        case files
    }
}

struct DetailGist: Codable {
    var filename: String?
    var rawUrl: String?

    private enum FileCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case filename
        case rawUrl = "raw_url"
    }
}
```

Is this the right model? Or it needs to be finalized? I'm confused by the

```
files =         {
            "gistfile1.txt" =
```

thanks!

Comment: @Connor That is the output of printing the JSON converted to an array using `JSONSerialization.jsonObject`. Nima's answer below is correct.

Comment: you can use http://www.json4swift.com/ to generate models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, files is a dictionary. That's what the `{}` markers in JSON mean. You want your Gists model to be

```
var files: [String: DetailGist]?
```